# Se espera un valor constante

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente error en c#:
Creo la variable "ano" y quiero comparar con otra variable ("verificar400") dentro de un switch.
No tuve problemas con este mismo codigo en visual basic. Pero en c# si, y no entiendo que significa el error.Por favor si lo ven, avisen, muchas gracias.

```
**class NumeroDiasDelMes
    {
        enum Meses : int
        {
            Enero = 1,
            Febrero = 2,
            Marzo = 3,
            Abril = 4,
            Mayo = 5,
            junio = 6,
            Julio = 7,
            Agost = 8,
            Septiembre = 9,
            Octubre = 10,
            Noviembre = 11,
            Diciembre = 12
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            int ano, resultado4, verificar4, resultado100, verificar100, resultado400, verificar400;
            int bisiesto = 2;
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese el Año");
            ano = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            resultado4 = ano / 4;
            verificar4 = resultado4 * 4;
            Console.WriteLine(verificar4);
            resultado100 = ano / 100;
            verificar100 = resultado100 * 100;
            Console.WriteLine(verificar100);
            resultado400 = ano / 400;
            verificar400 = resultado400 * 400;
            Console.WriteLine(verificar400);
            

            switch (verificar400)
            {
                case ano :
                //aqui en case ano linea de error
                    Console.WriteLine("Es bisiesto");
                    bisiesto = 1;
                    break;
            }**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los casos del switch deben ser valores constantes:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        // la variable año es constante
        const int año = 1;
        
        switch(1){
          
            case año:
                Console.WriteLine("año");
                break;
         
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No es posible, a menos que tu `ano` sea constante y no variable.

Es algo ya definido oficialmente por microsoft:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0150